# Reveal.js: Change Fragment animation timing/duration

Tags: reveal.js

The default Fragment animation duration/timing is too fast for my needs - I want to slow the fragment animation down to about 1.5 seconds.

*Auto-Animate* has [`data-auto-animate-duration`](https://revealjs.com/auto-animate/#animation-settings) and I'm looking for a similar setting for Fragments.

Looking through the [Reveal.js documentation](https://revealjs.com/fragments/) I can't figure out how to set this, or indeed if it is even supported.

Does anyone have a tip for controlling fragment animation duration/timing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a CSS based solution that uses `transition:` to change the animation speed to 1.5 seconds

```
.slides section .fragment { 
opacity: 0; 
visibility: hidden; 
transition: all 1.5s ease; }

.slides section .fragment.visible {

opacity: 1;

visibility: inherit; }
```